# I am trying to complete my UK IHS form but constantly getting error for intended date of travel

Tags: united-kingdom

I have completed my visa application and when trying to fill in IHS form to make payment, I am constantly getting error for intended date of travel to UK (i have tried to change dates, and also started a fresh application none of it worked). It also says that if I am not sure about the dates I can leave the space blank. But even then i get the same error. It wont let me complete the form. Has anyone else faced this issue or has a solution for this?

Comment: How are you entering the date? In 'day-month-year' format?

Comment: Yes, in the exact format mentioned on the form

Comment: SAME ISSUE HERE, ieven called them, they say it's a technical issue and that i should wait 48 hours

Comment: i have the same issue at the the moment, did anyone find a solution for this?